# Is there any way to prevent console application to close?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to prevent console application to close ?

(that the user can't close the program)

Comment: Please don't write programs where you try and prevent users from doing things like closing the application. That's just annoying :)

Comment: Will it be a problem for you if the user switches off the computer?

Comment: @Jason: No, that's just silly! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Win32 [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073(VS.85).aspx).

You could try creating a windows (non console app) and then create your own console window with AllocConsole(). As I haven't tried this I can't say if Windows will still try to kill your process.

An alternative would be to create a background process/service to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a console application can be aborted by pressing CTRL-C.

You can prevent CTRL-C from aborting your application by setting the [Console.TreatControlCAsInput property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.treatcontrolcasinput.aspx) or handling the [Console.CancelKeyPress event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.cancelkeypress.aspx).

Of course this won't stop the user from being able to kill your process, e.g. using Task Manager.

Comment: ... or using control-Break to stop it.